# stupid stl question

Tags: c++, memory-management, stl

I have following piece of code:

```
customObject* object;
std::list<customObject> objects;
for(int i = 0; i < 10: ++i) {
   object = new customObject;
   object.getvalue(i);
   objects.push_back(*object);
}
```

Will the memory be freed on successful exit?

Sorry, guys. Made some mistakes)) fixed

Comment: Maybe you mean `objects.push_back(*object);`?

Comment: There are syntax errors, some of them relevant in answering your question.

Comment: Is customObject* instead of CustomObject* a typo?

Comment: -1 @qutron I don't think you even try to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you fix the syntax errors and actually *compile* and *run* your code (assuming you keep in the `new`), you will leak ten `customObject`s.

You must iterate over the `list` and `delete` each instance that you have `new`'d.

Consider whether your `list` *needs* to contain pointers... If it does, then consider using a smart pointer (but not a `std::auto_ptr`).

It is probably better just to store the objects themselves (which `std::list<customObject> objects` does).

Answer (score 3):

Since you've declared the `std::list` as:

```
std::list<customObject> objects; //not storing the pointers!
```

Then you don't need to create `customObject` using `new`. You should do this:

```
std::list<customObject> objects;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   customObject object;
   object.getvalue(i);
   objects.push_back(object); //store the object, not pointer!
}
```

---

In C++0x, this can be done very concisely with lambda expression, as:

```
std::list<customObject> objects(10);
int i=0;
std::for_each(objects.begin(),objects.end(),[&](customObject &obj){ 
     obj.getValue(i++);
 });
```

Comment: @Mihran:  replaced `:` with `;`. Is this *the* reason for the downvote?

Comment: @Mihran: I didn't find that interesting, as the error was irrelevant in answering the question. Though correcting it was not a bad idea, but it wasn't deserving downvote.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your code will not compile (using operator . on a pointer, pushing list into itself).  Second standard containers will free space they allocate, but not space you allocated with new, malloc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have a mismatch between the type of the std::list and the objects you are attempting to store in it.
`std::list<customObject> objects;`  This creates a list of customObjects not customObject pointers.
`std::list<customObject*> objects;`  This creates a list of customObject pointers.

As to whether the memory will be freed once the list goes out of scope; Note that the list will call the destructor of each element.  If you consider that pointers (regardless of type) are really just integer representations of memory addresses, and not objects with destructors; it should be clear that the list has no destructor to call.  Another way to think about it is that all stl containers use value semantics and never dereference pointers.

Answer (score 0):

No, the memory will not be "freed".  STL practices value semantics, and the container thinks it only "owns" the "value" of the pointer, not the object referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No... Also I'm not sure your code will work, since you are trying to store a pointer in a non-pointer list.

Answer (score 0):

The memory will be freed by OS but only after the program has exited.

If you want to free the memory while your program is running you need to call delete on every pointer stored. Or use Boost Pointer Container Library to free the pointers automatically. Another solution is to use `std::vector< std::shared_pointer<Item> >`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what is being asked -- since all allocs are free'ed once the program exits.

Comment: @Martin Kristiansen: The OP has asked 'Will the memory be freed on successful exit?'. I interpreted it as program exit.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**
STL containers do not release memory allocated to pointer because they do not know if they have the sole ownership and hence the responsibility to deallocate the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind the syntactical errors you have: that of accessing members through a pointer and pushing the pointee onto a `std::list`. As for your question:

That depends. For all practical reasons **yes**: any modern operating system would take the memory it allocated for your process back when your process ends.

That said, as the process runs it is the process' responsibility to free memory it no longer needs. In your code above you introduce a *leak* in each iteration of the loop, because you never release the memory you allocated in the preceding iteration. This can translate to a system-wide slowdown, and at some point the OS can kill your process for being rude.